# Issue with vbscript emailing, unable to generate text body

Tags: email, vbscript

So I'm trying to send an e-mail with VBscripting and otherwise it works fine, but nothing I try to write to the txt or html body, appear on the message. Here is the function I'm using:

```
Function EMail( myFrom, myTo, mySubject, myTextBody, myHTMLBody, myAttachment, mySMTPServer, mySMTPPort )
' This function sends an e-mail message using CDOSYS
'
' Arguments:
' myFrom        = Sender's e-mail address ("John Doe <jdoe@mydomain.org>" or "jdoe@mydomain.org")
' myTo          = Receiver's e-mail address ("John Doe <jdoe@mydomain.org>" or "jdoe@mydomain.org")
' mySubject     = Message subject (optional)
' myTextBody    = Actual message (text only, optional)
' myHTMLBody    = Actual message (HTML, optional)
' myAttachment  = Attachment as fully qualified file name, either string or array of strings (optional)
' mySMTPServer  = SMTP server (IP address or host name)
' mySMTPPort    = SMTP server port (optional, default 25)
'
' Returns:
' status message
'

    ' Standard housekeeping
    Dim i, objEmail

    ' Use custom error handling
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Create an e-mail message object
    Set objEmail = CreateObject( "CDO.Message" )

    ' Fill in the field values
    With objEmail
        .From     = myFrom
        .To       = myTo
        ' Other options you might want to add:
        ' .Cc     = ...
        ' .Bcc    = ...
        .Subject  = mySubject
        .TextBody = myTextBody
        .HTMLBody = myHTMLBody
        If IsArray( myAttachment ) Then
            For i = 0 To UBound( myAttachment )
                .AddAttachment Replace( myAttachment( i ), "\", "\\" ),"",""
            Next
        ElseIf myAttachment <> "" Then
            .AddAttachment Replace( myAttachment, "\", "\\" ),"",""
        End If
        If mySMTPPort = "" Then
            mySMTPPort = 25
        End If
        With .Configuration.Fields
            .Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"      ) = 2
            .Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"     ) = mySMTPServer
            .Item( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport" ) = mySMTPPort
            .Update
        End With
    End With
    ' Return status message
    If Err Then
        EMail = "ERROR " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        objEmail.send
        If Err Then
            EMail = "ERROR " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            Err.Clear
        Else
            EMail = "ok"
        End If
    End If

    ' Release the e-mail message object
    Set objEmail = Nothing
    ' Restore default error handling
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

And here is how I'm calling it:

```
MsgBox Email ( "address@sender.com", _
             address@receiver.com, _
             "This subject appears on the email correctly", _
             "But this txt body does not", _
             "", _
             "", _
             "mail.smtp-server.com", _
             25 )
```

Like I said, the e-mail goes through alright, attachments work, subject works but for whatever reason the body never appears in the message! What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text use `TextBody`, for HTML use `HTMLBody` don't set both, currently you set `HTMLBody` to `""` which will override `TextBody`.

You could use a flag argument;

```
Function EMail( myFrom, myTo, mySubject, myBody, isHTML, myAttachment...
```

Then

```
if isHTML then 
    .HTMLBody = myBody
else
    .TextBody = myBody
end if
```